# Xcodeにおけるビルドエラー

Tags: xcode, apple, llvm

Timelineを作成するため、openframeworksはof_V0.9.3_osx_releaseをクローンしています。

https://openframeworks.cc/versions/v0.9.3/of_v0.9.3_osx_release.zip
https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/0.9.3

Xcodeでプロブラムを書きビルドすると
`Apple LLVM 9.0 Error`の`error reading`というエラーが出ます。
この場合の対処法はどのようなものがありますか。

このエラーは、はじめにビルドした後、addonの部分で`no such file or director`というエラーが出ていた時に以下の手順を行った後に出るようになりました

1. `プロジェクト -> TARGETS -> Build settings` へ移動
2. `Apple LLVM compiler`の項目の`Prefix Header`のパスをダウンロードしたaddonの場所に変更
3. `no such〜`のエラーがなくなり、今度は前記のエラーが出てきました

**環境**

- Xcodeのバージョン
  Xcode 9.0

Comment: Xcodeのプロジェクト情報の中で何らかのビルドに関する設定が壊れてしまっているものと思われますが、ご記載の情報だけではビルド設定(膨大な…)が全部正しいか確かめてみてくださいとしか言いようがありません。より詳しい情報をご記載くださるようお願いします。エラーメッセージ等はXcode左側のNavigator領域でReport navigator(右端、吹き出しの中に2本線のアイコン)を辿るとコピペ可能な形で閲覧できます。また、Xcodeのバージョン、ビルドしようとしたプロジェクトの種別なども解決の役に立つことがあるので、できるだけおしらせください。

Comment: 情報の追記ありがとうございます。編集が面倒なコメントスペースではちょっと大変なくらいしっかり書いてくださろうとしているようですが、ご自身の質問は「編集」できますので、質問内に追記してくだされば、より読みやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。XcodeのバージョンはXcode 9.0、Timelineを作成するため、openframeworksはof_V0.9.3_osx_releaseをクローンしています。エラーですが、はじめにビルドしたものに、addonの部分に＂no such file or director"というエラーが出たため、プロジェクト -> TARGETS -> Build settings へ移動し、「Apple LLVM compiler の項目の"Prefix Header"のパスをダウンロードしたaddonの場所に変更したらno such〜のエラーはなくなりましたが、今度はこのエラーが出て来たという状況です。